# Deployment to the non-appBase location on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat 7 is in use.

Deployment to the `appBase` location:

- Put the WAR file `myapp.war` under `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/`
- Browse to `http://localhost:8080/myapp` -> ok

Deployment to the `non-appBase` location:

- Move the WAR file `myapp.war` to `/path/to/nonappbase/`
- Create the context file `myctx.xml` under `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/` below,

  `<context 
   docBase="/path/to/nonappbase/"
   reloadable="true" >
  </context>`
- Browse to `http://localhost:8080/myctx` -> not found

Why did the Deployment to the `non-appBase` location fail?

**@EDIT**

According to the answer from `@Mads Nielsen`, it works now after the revision below,

`<Context docBase="/path/to/nonappbase/myapp.war" reloadable="true" />`

It's also evident that the `Context` element should be capitalized and in the shorthand form, i.e closed by `/>` instead of `</Context>`

Comment: It might just be a typo... is it `myctx` or `myapp` in the second scenario?

Comment: i've used `myctx` instead of `myapp` for the `non-appBase` deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` tag should point to a specific web application, not a path to a collection of web apps.

Add `myapp.war` to the docBase attribute in your context, and I'm sure it'll work.

See the `docBase´ attribute documentation here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html :

> The Document Base (also known as the Context Root) directory for this
>   web application, or the pathname to the web application archive file
>   (if this web application is being executed directly from the WAR
>   file).